# Missing "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" while App distribution

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox

I got strange issue with app distribution to Mac App Store.

I got MainApp and HelperApp. http://take.ms/GS3sRn

After being uploaded i receive mail from Apple.

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Monosnap". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> App sandbox not enabled - The following executables must include the
>   "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of
>   true in the entitlements property list. Refer to the App Sandbox page
>   for more information on sandboxing your app.
>
> Monosnap.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/MonosnapLauncher.app/Contents/MacOS/MonosnapLauncher
>   Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page
>   and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission
>   process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then
>   deliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

At the project level all items are sandboxed:
1 - http://take.ms/9S9BJ
2 - http://take.ms/nFNY9

Here the result of checking with terminal 
.entitlement file has correct info
codesign from terminal gives me this : http://take.ms/j4o2vh

How can i enable sandbox to helperApp?

Comment: Your terminal output from codesign shows that the key com.apple.security.app-sandbox is missing. It looks to me like the setup of your Info.plist for the app is wrong (maybe missing values), so it's coming up with com.apple.application-identifier. I'd suggest checking the Info.plist for the helper app. Is the CFBundleIdentifier set correctly?

Comment: http://take.ms/OxsHJS here's my MonosnapLauncher plist. And here the valid profiles http://take.ms/DMsSR . It's seems to be ok.

Comment: hm... i got new pack of errors : http://take.ms/5Ioa55

Comment: To me, that looks like a wrong project setting somewhere. If you can't find it, I suggest starting a new xcode project and copy the source files in and see if that build works.

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode 5, what you only need to do is turning "App Sandbox" on in Capabilities tab for your project target. It'll generate a file named **project_name.entitlements** for you automatically.

[image]

This works for me, and it changed to "Waiting for Review" state now. ;)